# Send string to a output file

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, config, stringbuilder

Currently I have data in a string with via this line of code

```
Console.WriteLine(TemplateMemoryBuilder.ToString());
```

I would like to output the string into a file. Either a (.config) file or (.txt). Trying to generate code to create the config file out of the string builder. My The File path/name is with the variable 'OutputFilePath'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way of writing a string to a file is to use [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx):

```
File.WriteAllText(OutputFilePath, TemplateMemoryBuilder.ToString());
```

Comment: Is there a specific way to indicate what type of file while doing this function?

Comment: @nerd04: What do you mean? If you're talking about a Word document or something like that, that's a completely different matter. If you just mean the file extension... well, that's part of the filename.

Comment: No didn't mean a word document. I think I see where he is coming from

Comment: @nerd04: No, but if you want to write an XML file you probably shouldn't be just coming up with text - you should use an XML API. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "some indicator" - you've just got a string, some text. The framework neither knows nor cares what meaning you attach to that data.

Comment: Initially when I was thinking through something I was saying 'indicator' as in the code shouldn't it be telling me its writing to a (.file).....had a brain fart for a minute...lol

Comment: After running this piece, it is working correctly. Need some logic based on the fact I am getting values from another file. Currently updating things that are in the DOM when I run the program. Have to add a piece before this to harness those attributes to be loaded inro ourput